# how do I display the data from the loop but wait for the loop to finish one by one?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to display data from a loop, but I want the data to be displayed one by one. when the data above has been read, the data below will be automatically read. because here I use urlopen. when I directly throw the data data into the url, the url automatically blocks this data throw. The following code that I made

```
import json
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import urlopen
import time
import sys
from pathlib import Path
import os
from urllib.error import HTTPError, URLError
import socket
import threading
from sched import scheduler
from time import time, sleep

print ("Data Scanner")

addr = input("Put file : id.txt ")

data_folder = os.path.dirname(__file__)
file_to_open = os.path.relpath(str(addr), data_folder)

f = open(file_to_open)
DoOpen = f.read().split(',')
totalDoOpen = len(DoOpen)
print("Total Data : " + str(len(DoOpen)))
for xloop in DoOpen:
    urladdr = "http://bagikantrik.com/" + str(xloop)
    addrdata = json.load(urlopen(urladdr))
    print('\a')
    print("URL : " + urladdr)
    print (str(addrdata['title']))
```

`id.txt` is a list of all data that I will send to the url. the code reads all the id from id.txt.
the contents of `id.txt` are like this `abc123,bca321,fgh412,ksi948`. so I want if the url of data from `abc123` has already loaded then the next data will load the url `bca321` and so on.

please help me, sorry if the question I'm asking is unclear

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure of the problem you are solving. But answering question in the header:
You can add some list before loop execution and append to that loop at the end of a loop. And later print from it

If the problem is the duplicates in file - put it in set to delete duplicates